# Property 'subscribe' in type 'ObservableMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Subscribable<MediaChange>'

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I just did an `ng upgrade` to my Angular 6 application and now I get:

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/flex-layout/core/typings/observable-media/observable-media.d.ts(11,14): error TS2416: Property 'subscribe' in type 'ObservableMedia' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Subscribable<MediaChange>'.
  Type '(next?: (value: MediaChange) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void) => Sub...' is not assignable to type '{ (observer?: PartialObserver<MediaChange>): Unsubscribable; (next?: (value: MediaChange) => void...'.
    Types of parameters 'next' and 'observer' are incompatible.
      Type 'PartialObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
        Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' is not assignable to type '(value: MediaChange) => void'.
          Type 'NextObserver<MediaChange>' provides no match for the signature '(value: MediaChange): void'.
src/app/core/order-store.service.ts(152,7): error TS2345: Argument of type 'MonoTypeOperatorFunction<any[]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<Order, any[]>'.
  Types of parameters 'source' and 'source' are incompatible.
    Type 'Observable<Order>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
      Type 'Order' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
        Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Order'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The upgrade of RxJS from 6.2 to 6.3 (sadly) changed the subscribe interface which broke `flex-layout`. Fortunately, `flex-layout` published a fix; update to the latest:

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "6.0.0-beta.18",
```

and install it:

```
npm install @angular/flex-layout
```

Comment: That would also install the [`reinstall`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reinstall) package, whereas you probably just wanted to re-install `@angular/flex-layout`

Comment: Thanks, @Stefan -- fixed now.